# Titanium: Saving file locally from Android's Camera/Gallery image

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, android-camera, titanium-mobile

I am having issues saving image to local application files in Titanium.
Specifically creating file from event.media;

```
function handleImageEvent(event) {
   imgpreview.image = event.media;

   var imaget = event.media;        
   var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,imagename); 
   f.write(imaget);

}

//imagename :  I am using in the format of 'photo0.png'
```

Here's the code I have so far that I have tried to put together and test through my own search,
they do not work. exception were thrown

```
[WARN] :   TextView: TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.
[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy: (KrollRuntimeThread) [5233,84017] IOException encountered
[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy: java.io.IOException: read only
[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy:     at org.appcelerator.titanium.io.TiResourceFile.write(TiResourceFile.java:100)
[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy:     at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiFileProxy.write(TiFileProxy.java:286)
[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy:     at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeFireEvent(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy:     at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.fireEvent(V8Object.java:62)
[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy:     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.doFireEvent(KrollProxy.java:884)
[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy:     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1107)
[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy:     at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:347)
[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

[ERROR] :  TiFileProxy:     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:112)

I hope I can provide more details, but I am at lost, apologies
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add the whole exception?

Comment: I have added the exception, upon my second inspection I am not certain if it is related or not, could be linking anther issue I posted found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060291/cannot-write-to-file-in-titanium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory` is read-only. Please find a list of all location, including the access rights at http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Filesystem_Access_and_Storage-section-29004902_FilesystemAccessandStorage-Storagelocations